# Problems with ajax call in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

****SOLVED by Splash-X - (see comments)*******

I am fairly new to ajax and jquery so I am sure I have made a simple error here but hours of trawling google have not helped me so i am really hoping someone here can. The code for the ajax call is below. It may or may not be relevent but the code below is itself being loaded by an ajax call very similar to the one below.

The content is loading fine in all browsers but the code within the ajax complete function isn't working in IE9 - jscrollpane is not being loaded and the jquery to resize elements is not working. The code works fine in the latest versions of FF and safari. Please let me know if you need to see any of the other code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$('ul.sort_ul li, ul.cat_items li').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('sort_cat')){
        $('ul.sort_ul li, ul.cat_items li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var sid=$(this).attr('id');
        var loadUrlx='<? base_url(); ?>games/ajax_dbr';
        if((sid!='')&&(sid!='undefined')){loadUrlx+='/'+sid}
        $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false}); 
        var ajax_load = "<div class=\"loader_res_small\"><img src='http://www.imgshack.co.uk/images/site/ajaxloader.gif' alt='loading...' /></div>";
        $("#result_area").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrlx);
            $('#result_area').ajaxComplete(function() {
                $('#result_area').jScrollPane();

                //get td width and set width of table headers
                var tdname = $(".tdname").width();
                $("#s_name").width(tdname-11); 
                var tdcat = $(".tdcat").width();
                $("#s_cat").width(tdcat-10);
                var tdur = $(".tdrateu").width();
                $("#s_ur").width(tdur-10);
                var tdor = $(".tdrateo").width();
                $("#s_or").width(tdor-10);

        });
    }

});
```

******* *REVISED CODE WHICH NOW WORKS ON ALL BROWSERS* ****************

```
$('ul.sort_ul li, ul.cat_items li').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('sort_cat')){
        $('ul.sort_ul li, ul.cat_items li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var sid=$(this).attr('id');
        var loadUrlx='<? base_url(); ?>games/ajax_dbr';
        if((sid!='')&&(sid!='undefined')){loadUrlx+='/'+sid}
        $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false}); 
        var ajax_load = "<div class=\"loader_res_small\"><img src='<? base_url(); ?>images/site/ajaxloader.gif' alt='loading...' /></div>";
        $("#result_area").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrlx, function() {
                $('#result_area').jScrollPane();

                //get td width and set width of table headers
                var tdname = $(".tdname").width();
                $("#s_name").width(tdname-11); 
                var tdcat = $(".tdcat").width();
                $("#s_cat").width(tdcat-10);
                var tdur = $(".tdrateu").width();
                $("#s_ur").width(tdur-10);
                var tdor = $(".tdrateo").width();
                $("#s_or").width(tdor-10);

        });
    }
```

});

Comment: The .load event in jQuery has a callback for when the call is complete. Is there a reason you didn't use that? Ex:  $("#result_area").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrlx, function(){ alert('Move my function here'); });

Comment: Not sure if you had a chance to read my last comment but I just tried what you suggested and now it works.... You sir are a genius!!!!

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer so you can "accept" the answer if you want it marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .load event in jQuery has a callback for when the call is complete.
Example usage would be:

```
 $("#result_area").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrlx, function(){
      alert('Move my function here');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks splash, this fix has solved the main isssue but for some reason my scroll bars not working now.... nevermind I feel I am a step further forward, at least some of the code is running and I should have a fighting chance at sorting it out now if not... I'll be back. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume you don't have

```
<? base_url(); ?>
```

actually in your code.

Otherwise I've no idea how different browsers would handle what is apparently an xml processing directive, and it could vary a lot.

Perhaps this is meant to be served out via an interpreter? Otherwise, put the string value of the actual base URL in place of this string.

Comment: I do, I'm using codeigniter... will change that now.... But the solution was to use the ajax .load callback function instead of ajaxcomplete as suggested by Splash-X. Thank you all for quick responses and view - especially Splash. Now if only I knew how to mark this as solved....